# How to enable RDP on KVM

Tags: vnc, kvm-virtualization, qemu, rdp

I installed **KVM** on a ubuntu natty server. I created a Windows XP Pro virtual machine that works perfectly and catch up with **VNC**, follow the setup string:
`<graphics type='vnc' port='5900' autoport='no' listen='0.0.0.0'/>`

**But I would like to use RDP:**
`<graphics type='rdp' port='3389' autoport='no' multiUser='yes' />`

When I start the virtual machine I get the following error:
kwm@root:~# virsh start WinXP1

Error: Unable to start domain WinXP1

Error: unsupported configuration: unsupported graphics type 'rdp'

I must add a module or a library to make it work?

Tx in advance

Answer (score 3):

KVM only supports VNC, not RDP.

The documentation you saw that mentions RDP is libvirt, which is a general purpose library which supports multiple types of virtual machine - including KVM, Xen, KXC, OpenVZ, VirtualBox, VMWare etc.

RDP is a mentioned in the documentation because some of the VMs do support it, but not all - eg VirtualBox uses RDP but KVM does not.

Answer (score 2):

You do not configure rdp on the host, you do so within windows.

So on the host, leave the graphics type "vnc"

Boot windows and enable rdp (desktop sharing). Then connect over rdp and not vnc.

Comment: This is exactly what I already do, but I would like to delete the network interfaces of the Windows machine to prevent browsing  and since I need a service with multiple users simultaneously I wanted to use RDP instead of VNC. Furthermore, using an outside service I lighten the virtual machine.

Comment: Well, you are sort of stuck if you want to use RDP as there is no RDP server build into KVM.

Comment: If there is no RDP server built in KVM, why in the documentation is explained the method to activate it?
Perhaps it has not been implemented yet?

http://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#elementsGraphics

Comment: @Nitrox libvirt supports many virtualization platforms.  Some of these (such as VirtualBox) support RDP, but KVM / QEMU do not, that's why it's in the docs despite not being supported.  I've been looking for better options than VNC as well, but have yet to find anything promising.